# Account created on Data Explorer not linking to my other SE accounts

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer, user-accounts, openid

I wanted to check [How unsung am i?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i) on **data.stackexchange** .Later I just thought to create an account on it using my google account which i use on other stackexchange sites on which i was already logged in(stackoverflow). But when i click on **login with Google** it automatically creates an account with username **jon.doe12878** which is not even linked to my already existing accounts.Below is the screen-shot of list of accounts displayed on my stackoverflow profile:

---

[image: Profile-stackoverflow accounts list]

See  **data.stackexchange** account is not displayed on my stackoverflow accounts list.

---

Below is the screen shot of my **data.stackexchange** account:

[image: data.stackexchange account info]

I dont know why this is happening and I really what to know the reason

Comment: See also: [Data Explorer FAQ](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq)

Comment: thanks @TimStone .I searched on google and didnt find this result.May be my keywords didnt match.If the question is duplicate should i delete it?

Comment: @Zword Don't delete; it'll be useful for anyone in the future using the same keywords.

Comment: That's your call, it doesn't really matter.